# Deadlock error is not occuring in this code?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

Take a look at this code . When a thread acquires a synchronized method in object x and another thread acquires synchronized method on object y , x cant call synchronized method on object y. and y cant call sync method on x . This is the theory that i learned in book . Now look at this code

```
import java.io.*;

class classx
{
    synchronized void method_on_x()
    {
        System.out.println("method on class x");
    }
}

class classy
{
    synchronized void method_on_y()
    {
        System.out.println("method on class y");
    }
}

class accessx implements Runnable
{
    classx cx1;
    classy cy1;
    Thread t;

    public accessx(classx cx, classy cy)
    {
        t = new Thread(this);
        cx1 = cx;
        cy1 = cy;
        t.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        cx1.method_on_x();
        cy1.method_on_y();
    }
}

class accessy implements Runnable
{
    classx cx1;
    classy cy1;
    Thread t;

    public accessy(classx cx, classy cy)
    {
        t = new Thread(this);
        cx1 = cx;
        cy1 = cy;
        t.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        cy1.method_on_y();
        cx1.method_on_x();
    }
}

class multizync
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        classx c1 = new classx();
        classy c2 = new classy();
        accessx a1 = new accessx(c1, c2);
        accessy a2 = new accessy(c1, c2);
        try
        {
            a1.t.join();
            a2.t.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("mAIN tHREAD eXECUTION cOMPLETED");
    }
}
```

This code creates two thread classes accessx and accessy which calls two synchronized methods each on its own instance.how can it happen. When accessx thread has

```
synchronized method_on_x
```

it cant call

```
synchronized method_on_y
```

which accessy has isn't it. Then why dont i get the error.

Comment: They release their locks immediately after printing.

Comment: Add a wait() statement inside your synchronized methods so that you can see the locking effect.

Comment: No, not even. To get the deadlock, you'd have to ask for lock y when having lock x and asking for lock x when having lock y.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis .. there is one more question,  if there is a single thread in a program and two objects each has it own sychronized method. can the thread access both the synchronized method on the same time. Is it possible.?

Comment: That seems pretty trivial. Try it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis . Tried it. But no error. Am i right with the concept on deadlock . Did i had it clear. Because the above code , i created on my own understanding.

Comment: Your code will never demonstrate deadlock. Change it to reflect what I posted in my second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any deadlock situation in your code:

- a1 sequentially calls method_on_x and method_on_y
- a2 sequentially calls method_on_y and method_on_x

Yes, a1 and a2 run in two different threads and they can wait for an access to a synchronized method, but only for a insignificant amount of time, since as soon as "print" operation is completed, the method becomes available for calls coming from another thread.

Comment: So can i just add either a wait() method inside the two synchronized methods to achieve deadlock .. ??

Comment: It still will not be a deadlock. A synchronized method will be blocked for a duration of wait time. That's the reason why you need to make sure that all your synchronized methods execute fast, otherwise they can be a bottleneck for queued threads, but it's still not a deadlock.

Comment: @ Oleg Gryb . Oh . I need to learn more i think . tell me this brother,  Can a single thread access two synchronized methods at the same time.? Is it possible. ?